# 2000 Chevy Camaro starts, idles low around 1000 rpms for 4 or 5 seconds before dying

Tags: starting, chevrolet, manual-transmission, idle

It's a 2000 Camaro v6 manual.

Most days the car starts just fine but on other days I might have to start it 20 times before it stays on.

When I start it, the RPM is around 1000 but slowly drops to around 800 before it dies.

If I apply the gas as the car starts it will die almost instantly.

I just replaced the battery but I'm afraid I stripped the battery terminals.

Today, after trying to start it 15 or so times, I had to pull the keys out the ignition, wait a minute, and start it before it stayed on. I'm not if pulling the keys out the ignition helped.

Comment: How's the acceleration? It sounds like you might have a dirty air filter or an obstruction in the air intake.  How does the car perform once it's warm?

Comment: Sounds a lot like a bad fuel pump or fuel pump relay.

Comment: @TMN, The acceleration seems decent to me. The air filter is clean. If the car makes it more than 10 or 15 feet in reverse then I know it's good. Most times when it has done this I made it 2 feet in reverse before it cut out and gets stuck in this loop.

Comment: I second @hillsons--this smacks of dying fuel pump. If you're not comfortable addressing that yourself, I'd save money on a tow by making sure to drive it to a shop the very next time it starts!

Comment: ......hmm. It's possible it could be the ignition switch, actually, but your observations about the RPMs have me second-guessing now. The 15-20 attempts to start, followed by killing the engine on initial acceleration were identical to trouble I had with my '97 Blazer. Let me ask ..do the dashboard lights come on properly before you crank it, vs. when you crank it and it starts? ....like this: http://youtu.be/E0iDZUD7M2A

Comment: The car is not in my possession anymore. A friend has it now but they haven't driven it in a while. If they want to get it running good again ill refer them here. Thanks anyway